# Get PostgreSQL resultset column types without executing query using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, psycopg2

Given an arbitrary PostgreSQL query, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (...) AS T`, how can I get resultset column names and types **WITHOUT** actually executing the query using psycopg2 Python3 library?

I saw [JDBC solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110018/177275) using getMetaData(), but I cannot figure out how to get that same information in psycopg2.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select ... ");
ResultSetMetaData meta = pstmt.getMetaData();
for (int i=1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, that's not possible without executing(running `cur.execute()`)

But, If you want a Postgres solution using a function that can be used by Psycopg2 as a query, you may use this solution. As you were expecting, this will **not execute** your query, it simply creates a temporary `View` which allows us to query it's metadata using the catalog `information_schema.columns`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function define_query(query text) 
  RETURNS TABLE( column_name text,data_type text)  
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  
$$ 
DECLARE 
v_view_n TEXT := 'temp_view$'; 
BEGIN 
       EXECUTE format( 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW  %I AS %s', v_view_n,query);
       RETURN QUERY  select i.column_name::text, i.data_type ::text
           from information_schema.columns i where i.table_name = v_view_n;
END $$;
```

Once you've got this function, you can get the definition of any query by simply calling this function and not executing it.

```
knayak=# select * from define_query('select 1::int as a,''TWO''::text as b');
 column_name | data_type
-------------+-----------
 a           | integer
 b           | text
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Is there a way to somehow analyze the prepared statement, just like it is done in JDBC code?  And Kaushik, thank you for a thourough example, but I am really uneasy about modifying DB when I only need to analyze it (esp consider when I have a read-only access or if i'm hitting a mirror)

Comment: @Yurik : I may not have clearly mentioned but this is just one way of accomplishing it. If there are better alternatives, I would be glad to know myself. As far as modifying database is concerned, it just creates a stored function and a temporary view(with no data).So, there shouldn't a reason for unease.

Comment: thanks, I am just worried that in a master-slave scenario, multiple instances could conflict by creating identical objects, plus in some cases I would make DB readonly to prevent accidental data corruption by non-data changing users, so this solution might not work in those cases.

Comment: @Yurik : temp views are created for a session and dropped automatically when exited from a session. So multiple sessions should not create problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to execute something at least.

If you don't want any rows returned, you can query like `select * from XXX where false`. This query will return types of columns to client with 0 rows.

Comment: Heh, I was so hopping of somehow analyzing prepared statement or something like that... but your solution should work, thanks!